# How to Check if User entered text contains http:// in Javascript

Tags: javascript, url

I have a setup like, My website ask the user for entering a URL. Sometimes user enters like `http://google.com/` and other times `google.com`, but my application supports URL with `http://` or `https://`,
 I tried this:

```
var a = document.getElementById('tinput').value;
if (a.indexOf(escape('http://')) < 0 && a.indexOf(escape('https://')) < 0){
b = 'http://' + a;
document.getElementById('tinput').value = b;
}
document.getElementById("urlfrm").submit();
```

But this dint work. It always adds `http://` to all the URL even if they contain the same. What to do?

Comment: did you try removing escape() ? because it converts your https:// into https%3A//

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var field = document.getElementById('tinput');
if (!/^https?:\/\//.test(field.value)) field.value = 'http://'+field.value;
```

A couple of points to note:

- your current check allows for `http(s)://` to be anywhere in the string - you should check for it at the start only
- in the interests of code readability, and because the only value under zero that `indexOf()` can return is -1, it's better to check for that explicitly, rather than `< 0`
- you're creating a global variable (`b`) for no reason
- don't escape - as xdevel said in his comment, this will mean you check for an encoded version of the string, not the string itself

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var a = document.getElementById('tinput').value;
if (a.indexOf('http://') == -1 && a.indexOf('https://') == -1){
b = 'http://' + a;
document.getElementById('tinput').value = b;
document.getElementById("urlfrm").submit();
} else {
document.getElementById("urlfrm").submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply with regular expressions, well worth learning about them.

```
if ( a.match("^https?://") ) {
    alert("a is a url");
}
```